# Unknown Element - Angular 2 With Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Beating my head against the wall at this point. I'm getting an error when running an angular 2 app using SystemJS and angular material, can't figure out why. I am using the angular-seed project: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed. I added material via this guideline: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Integration-with-AngularMaterial2.

**Error:**

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-toolbar' is not a known element:`

***home.component.html***

`<md-toolbar>Test</md-toolbar>`

***SystemJS Config***

`this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
      ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
      {src: '@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css', inject: true}
      // {src: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
      // {src: 'lodash/lodash.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
    ];
    this.addPackageBundles({
        name:'@angular/material',
        path:'node_modules/@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
        packageMeta:{
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    });`

*Note that it appears the files are loading in the browser when inspecting sources with dev tools*

***App Module***

```
...
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, MaterialModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, AboutModule, HomeModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
  ...
```

***package.json***

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  }
  ...
```

***Home Component***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NameListService } from '../shared/name-list/name-list.service';

/**
 * This class represents the lazy loaded HomeComponent.
 */
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

**Q** - How can I fix this unknown element issue? Thanks!

Comment: Check inside `package.json` your material version.

Comment: import  `MaterialModule` only instead of `MaterialModule.forRoot()` and check.

Comment: @Kinduser - Added the package.json for you.

Comment: @micronyks - That does not fix or change the error, thanks though.

Comment: what errors do u get?

Comment: is HomeComponent declared inside of the HomeModule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the last version says [(2.0.0-beta.3 cesium-cephalopod (2017-04-07)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)) you must import the `MdToolbarModule` in the module that loads `home.component`.

If the module is the `home.module`, just load the `MdToolbarModule` there, like this:

```
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        MdToolbarModule, // HERE YOU IMPORT THE TOOLBAR MODULE. IF YOU WANT ONLY THIS MODULE IN YOUR BUILD
        ...
],
...
```

This is needed because of AOT and Lazy Load. This is the only way Angular can remove unnecessary code. If you don't load the module in every module that need this, the compiler will never know who uses this and will need to append it in all components even if it is not a lazy component.

The reason you don't need to load `MaterialModule` in other components but in `app.module` is that `app.module` is your entry point and it is always loaded no matter which lazy module you are loading. We can say that `app.module` is the father of every module, being them lazy or not.

So, if you load a module in `app.module` using `forRoot()` it means that you created a global instance of the module `services` and all child components will have access to thaqt services. This is the reason you don't need to load `material.module` in `home.module` again, because `MaterialModule` is used to load services used by Material to connect material components. That is all MaterialModule do.

Each material component is plug-and-play if you already loaded `MaterialModule` in the father component.

For modules loaded without `forRoot()`, you won't have a singleton services so you will need to load it in every component. All this is necessary to allow a better tree shaking where you only have what you need in your build.

Comment: DOH! Of course it is something so obvious. Appreciate you looking in to this. It was indeed because the seed project I used has those separate modules... would you be able to articulate *why* they decided to put each component into its own module?

Comment: To me, the individual modules are an internal implementation detail of Angular Material. At one point, they used to recommend that you import the individual modules that you're using, but with the move to better tree shaking support, they now specify MaterialModule as the module that you're supposed to import.

Comment: @vinagreti, I don't think your comments are correct. He NEEDS to import MaterialModule in the HomeModule, whether or not he already imported it in the AppModule. And since the MaterialModule import is already there, the MdToolbarModule import is made redundant

Comment: @Snorkpete I've updated the response with more details.

Comment: @vinagreti, you're right about the services - when you import MaterialModule into the AppModule, its services become accessible from the root injector, which basically means you can use MaterialModule services from anywhere.  However, the same is NOT true for declarables (components, directives, pipes i.e. stuff you use in your templates).  For the declarables of MaterialModule, you have to import them in EVERY module that you use them  (or again, import another module that exports the MaterialModule)

Comment: B@Snorkpete I've updated the response with more details. But about redundancy, your statement is wrong. It is all about lazy loaded. MaterialModule is a glue for its components. It is not a component either a Module for all components. It is just a bunch of services used by material modules. You will have to load the modules in every module that needs this. This is the only way Angular can know if a lazy loaded module needs some other module (mdToolbarModule in this case) to insert it in the lazy loaded module budle.

Comment: @Snorkpete, I did not find docs about this, but for me, I only load `MaterialModule` in `app.module` and in children I load only the component module as `mdInputModule` `mdIconModule`. And AOT is working like a charm. You can be right when you say that we need to load, but the use case does not prove your point.

Comment: @vinagreti, in your same example, try importing MaterialModule (instead of MdInputModule) in the child component and you'll get the exact same behavior. The point is: u have to import the Module containing the components that u want to use in every module that you want to use them in. Whether you import them by importing MaterialModule or by importing the individual modules (MdInputModule, MdToolbarModule etc) is somewhat arbitrary. But if you have a feature module, it's not enough to just import MaterialModule in AppModule and be done with it. You also have to import into your feature module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137435/discussion-between-vinagreti-and-snorkpete).

Answer (score 1):

@karns, You mentioned the problem exists in the HomeComponent, and i noticed that in your imports list, there's a HomeModule.

Does HomeComponent belong to that HomeModule?

If so, did you import MaterialModule into your HomeModule?

You need to import the MaterialModule (or a module that exports MaterialModule) into every module that may use Angular Material components in its templates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Snork. It is correct, however I'm going to accept Vinagreti's answer since he has some example code. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :

1. Make sure that you used the below command to install the material in to your app

   ```
   npm install --save @angular/material
   ```
2. Go to node_modules and check if these files are present

   ```
   node_modules/@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js
   @angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css
   ```
3. If the above two files are there,

   - Delete the materials folder
   - Install it again
   - Before installation check if it is there as a dependency in the package.json file.
   - Check now if the above files are present now.
4. In the network tab of developer tools, check that you are having as below

[image]

Option 2 :

If the above solution did not work try with this

1. Include the below files in the index.html 
   [image]
2. In your config.js file **remove** the `@angular/material` line and use the below cdn reference

   '@angular/material': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HD8keUUA5EAAl5TWM2ew?p=preview)** to show that the cdn reference works

Update 1: The plunker is working fine now, you can have a look at it.

Explanation for option 2 is to use a cdn reference which does not care if you have the node_module installed or not, in most cases it will definitely work. If this cdn link fixes your problem. update me We shall try fixing the option 1 in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately option 1 didn't work. The files are there and, still, it errors. Would you elaborate on option 2 bullet #2, please? I'm assuming you mean the SystemJS config. Could you provide context for the code change?

Comment: @karns will have a look at it and update you in some time

Comment: Thanks for the help Aravind - really appreciate looking into this and you had some useful suggestions that ultimately narrowed down the issue, but didn't solve it. However, others answered correctly.